# Cronjob Not Running via Crontab -e

Tags: docker, powershell, cron, powercli

I am trying to run a script daily that connects to my ESXi host, deletes all snapshots of all my VMs, then creates new snapshots each day. I am attempting to do this by running the script within a docker container using the VMWare PowerCLI docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/vmware/powerclicore) on my docker VM running Ubuntu.

I am able to successfully run this script by running the following command in terminal:

`/usr/bin/docker run --rm -it --name=powerclicore --entrypoint="/usr/bin/pwsh" -v /home/<redacted>/config/powercli:/scripts vmware/powerclicore /scripts/VMSnapshot.ps1`

However, after adding the above command to my cronfile via `crontab -e`, my job is not running.

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                             /tmp/crontab.EZkliu/crontab                                                                                                       
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 0 * * * /usr/bin/docker run --rm -it --name=powerclicore --entrypoint="/usr/bin/pwsh" -v /home/<redacted>/config/powercli:/scripts vmware/powerclicore /scripts/VMSnapshot.ps1
```

Am I doing this wrong? A second pair of eyes would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think it would be better (and easier to maintain and update) to create a script file in /usr/local/bin (or other appropriate location for your system) and call that script from cron. You will not need to change cron every time you update the script.

Comment: @KazikM Thanks. I will try this. Quick question though: know how to get this job to run a lot sooner than waiting for 12 AM tonight?

Comment: Change this part `0 0 * * * ` to other value you want. You can check various combinations [here at Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_*). Just replace stars with other proper values. It can be even run multiple times a day, even every minute.

Comment: Hi @KazikM. Thanks for your response. So, I actually went a different route and determined that the command can be simplified to `/usr/bin/docker powerclicore-vmsnapshot start`. I confirmed that when I run this command as the current user, it executes successfully. However, when I add it to my crontab via `crontab -e` like this: `0 0 * * * /usr/bin/docker powerclicore-vmsnapshot start`, it does not seem to run since my VMs are not backing up. Do you have any idea as to why the command works when I run it manually but not by adding it to my crontab?

Comment: Looks like it can be docker-specific problem, but unfortunately I am not too familiar with docker. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, @KazikM. After some troubleshooting, I was finally able to get this to work using your recommendation. I created a Bash script that called the Docker command I was trying to put int crontab, then just called the Bash script using crontab: `0 0 * * * /bin/bash /home/<redacted>/config/powerclicore/VMSnapshot-bash.sh`. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@KazikM. After some troubleshooting, I was finally able to get this to work using your recommendation. I created a Bash script that called the Docker command I was trying to put int crontab, then just called the Bash script using crontab: `0 0 * * * /bin/bash /home/<redacted>/config/powerclicore/VMSnapshot-bash.sh`. Thanks again for your help!